# I m getting error User_ID_seq.nextval unknown column

Tags: java, mysql

```
    try {
    int c=1;
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(NHMQueryConstant.INSERT_INTO_USER.toString());

       pstmt.setInt(c++, userID);
       pstmt.setInt(2, userTypeID);
       pstmt.setString(c++,userName);
        pstmt.setString(c++,NameInHindi);
        pstmt.setString(c++,loginID);
        pstmt.setString(c++,password);

       int  result = Integer.parseInt(mobile);
       System.out.println(result);
      pstmt.setInt(c++,result);
       pstmt.setString(c++,email);
        System.out.println(email);
        /*
        java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dob);
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
        pstmt.setDate(c++, sqlDate);
        System.out.println(sqlDate);
        */
        //pstmt.setDate(++c,new Date(new java.util.Date().getTime()));
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
}



 public static final String INSERT_INTO_USER = new StringBuilder("")
    .append("INSERT INTO m_user_master (M_User_Id,User_Type_ID,M_User_Name,M__User_Name_Hindi,Login_ID,Password,Mobile,Email)")
        .append("VALUES(USER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,'2',?,?,?,?,?,?)").toString();
```

I m getting error User_ID_seq.nextval unknown column.how can I insert getting parameter index out of range.

Comment: Use JPA.  The way that you are doing it is open to SQL Injection attachks

Comment: I m using mysql and java .

Comment: Scary Wombat is right, by the way you are using wrong syntax for MySQL, if your table has AUTOINCREMENT field for user_id then you could do it as public static final String INSERT_INTO_USER = new StringBuilder("")
    .append("INSERT INTO m_user_master (User_Type_ID,M_User_Name,M__User_Name_Hindi,Login_ID,Password,Mobile,Email)")
        .append("VALUES('2',?,?,?,?,?,?)").toString();

Comment: Better public static final String INSERT_INTO_USER = "INSERT INTO m_user_master (User_Type_ID,M_User_Name,M__User_Name_Hindi,Login_ID,Passwo‌​rd,Mobile,Email) VALUES('2',?,?,?,?,?,?)"

Comment: but how i can pass date of birth as Date from front end text box and further store in database as Date datatype ..

Comment: You are mixing different things in one question. 1) USER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL is not supported by MySQL 2) "how i can pass date of birth as Date" - it depends on what format your frontend sends you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have autogenerated ID (e.g. AUTOINCREMENT in MySQL syntax) and don't want to care about id you could like this

```
public static final String INSERT_INTO_USER = "INSERT INTO " +
            "m_user_master (M_User_Name,M__User_Name_Hindi,Login_ID,Password,Mobile,Email)" +
            " VALUES('2',?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

And you have to remove

```
pstmt.setInt(c++, userID);
pstmt.setInt(2, userTypeID);
```

If you want to handle ID generation in Java then you can do it

```
public static final String INSERT_INTO_USER = "INSERT INTO " +
            "m_user_master (M_User_Id,M_User_Name,M__User_Name_Hindi,Login_ID,Password,Mobile,Email)" +
            " VALUES(?,'2',?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

and remove only

```
pstmt.setInt(2, userTypeID);
```